# Code::Blocks Compilation Errors

Tags: c++, compilation, mingw, codeblocks

I'm having some problems with Code::Blocks, and this is the output after / while compiling;

```
3|iostream: No such file or directory|
4|error: syntax error before "namespace"|
|In function `main':|
8|error: `cout' undeclared (first use in this function)|
8|error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once|
8|error: for each function it appears in.)|
||=== Build finished: 5 errors, 1 warnings ===|
```

My code is as follows;

```
// my first program in C++

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  cout << "Hello World!";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This won't fix it but you should say `using namespace std;`, although that's not recommended.

Comment: Are you sure that you have created C++ Console Project?

Comment: How do I do that? (I'm a complete newbie) I just did blank project?

Comment: File -> New Project -> Console Application -> C++

Comment: Michal, post that as an answer, as it solved my problem!

Comment: @PeterWood I'm sure this has been debated and discussed tons in the forum and elsewhere but I agree that putting a using statement in header files is not a good idea but don't see anything wrong with it in a source file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Have to Create Console C++ Project.

File -> New Project -> Console Application -> C++ .

It will set variables and linker options like basics libraries.

Answer (score 1):

The cout issue is because you should say

```
using namespace std;
```

The issue with iostreams is probably that you need to set the path to MINGW in your toolchain. You can access this from the Settings->Compiler and debugger settings->Global compiler setting->toolchain executables menus/tabs. Here select the part where MINGW is installed and that should take care of it.

Comment: My code does have using, but for some reason it got deleted when copying and pasting, I'll edit it. Thanks for the pointers!