# iostream library not included in codeblocks

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks, iostream

I'm currently trying codeblocks for my c++ programming but i'm having trouble getting it to compile, i have not had this problem in the past and i've only developed it recently, i have searched google in vain for a solution and the closest i came was [Code::Blocks Compilation Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403907/codeblocks-compilation-errors)
which did not fix my problem i have tried numerous times to uninstall and install both codeblocks and mingw.
the error is:

```
1|fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
```

it's just a basic hello world program in my settings i have the c++ compiler listed as mingw32-g++.exe. i have been trying for days to get this to work, please help.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
int main()
{
    cout << "hello world\n"; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you using iostream and iostream.h?

Comment: yes, it's just a straightforward #include <iostream> using namespace std; int main(){cout << "hello world\n"; return 0;}

Comment: Have you seen this FAQ? http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=FAQ-Compiling_%28errors%29#Q:_My_simple_C.2B.2B_program_throws_up_lots_of_errors_-_what_is_going_on.3F

Comment: thank for the reference john, i fixed the .c's on my files but now i'm coming up with ||=== helloworld.cpp, Debug ===|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `main':|
c:\Users\jnsouth\cpp\helloworld.cpp\main.cpp|6|multiple definition of `main'|
obj\Debug\euler35.o:c:\Users\jnsouth\cpp\helloworld.cpp\hello.cpp|5|first defined here|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 1 seconds) ===|

Comment: Well I'm not experienced with code blocks but it seems you have combined more than one program in your compilation. You have a helloworld.cpp and a euler35.cpp? Must admit I'm not really understanding those error messages in detail but it is telling you that somehow you've managed to include more than one main function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you misplace your iostream file?

Perhaps you could confirm this issue with another compiler.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and it was that I was saving the file as a c file (ex. HelloWorld.c). When I changed the file to HelloWorld.cpp started to works. So, change the file name to .cpp

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Using standard C++ calling (note that you should use namespace std for cout or add using namespace std;) */ 

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah i solve this 
just use a c++ compiler 
like g++ `g++ your project -o test`
and then`./test`
your project = the name of your text codes and 1 more note if u use g++
and your file is in desktop 
go to file manager and go to desktop and click right on the desktop (file manager)
and click on open terminal and then boom finish it

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same "#include<  iostream  > " No such file or directory ERROR!!
But probably in my case that was the extension problem. Codeblocks saves it in .c (extension by default.) Just Save the program by its name followed by cpp. Like "Myprogram.cpp". Hope this helps.....